# Why does adding rights to User group affect an Administrator (Server 2008)?

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-permissions

User Foo is logged and a member of Administrators, but not a member of Users - I removed that group and even rebooted. In `c:\inetpub\www` Foo cannot modify any files even though the Administrators group has full rights to the file.

If I give full rights directly to Foo, edit works. If I give full rights to the Users group, edit works. File and parent folder owner is System. What is going on?

Comment: Actually, on second thought this might belong in serverfault better than superuser - sorry!

Comment: The obvious suggestion is that Foo is a member of a group that is itself a member of Users.

Comment: Yeah but aren't the permissions positively recursive? Meaning that Foo is member of User and Administrator and only Administrators have write access to a file, Foo by extension has write access as well. To clarify: Foo is member of Administrators. Administrators have write access to file. Foo cannot write.